# Problem writing a custom loss function without numpy arrays using tensorflow 2.0 for image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, loss-function

I am trying to modify a working [implementation](https://github.com/mlyg/unified-focal-loss) of the Tversky loss function which is defined as:

[image: Tversky loss]

where  TP: True positive, FP: False positive, FN: False negative, 0<delta<1, and for delta=0.5 we get the dice loss.

I have ground truth labels (64x64) that are sparse and have few masks (equal to one) with size (3x3) as shown in this example:

[image: ground truth label]

My goal is to automatically set to zero predicted pixels that are close to a region in which the ground truth label equals to one. In this example, this would mean to force green pixels equal to zero in the predicted label.

[image: ground truth label with contour]

Here I have an implementation that uses numpy arrays, which I know is not possible for the loss function (made for one class only):

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
 
def identify_axis(shape):
    # Three dimensional
    if len(shape) == 5 : return [1,2,3]
    # Two dimensional
    elif len(shape) == 4 : return [1,2]
    # Exception - Unknown
    else : raise ValueError('Metric: Shape of tensor is neither 2D or 3D.')

def modified_tversky_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Paper: Tversky loss function for image segmentation using 3D fully convolutional deep networks
    Link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05721
    delta: controls weight given to false positive and false negatives. 
    this equates to the Tversky index when delta = 0.7
    smooth: smoothing constant to prevent division by zero errors
    """
    delta = 0.9
    smooth = 0.00001

    axis = identify_axis(y_true.get_shape())
    
    #### Part of the code that needs to be changed ####

    y_true_copy = y_true.numpy()
    y_pred_copy = y_pred.numpy()

    for batch in range(np.shape(y_true_copy)[0]):

        #### This part is used to get the bottom left coordinates of ground truth masks ####

        is_not_all_zero = np.any(y_true_copy[batch,:,:,0])
        pos_list = [] # list containing bottom left coordinates of ground truth masks
        while is_not_all_zero:
            pos = np.unravel_index(y_true_copy[batch,:,:,0].argmax(), y_true_copy.shape)
            y_true_copy[batch, pos[1]:pos[1]+3, pos[2]:pos[2]+3, 0] = 0
            pos_list.append(pos)
            is_not_all_zero = np.any(y_true_copy[batch,:,:,0])

        #### Using the bottom left coordinates of ground truth masks, we set to zero neighbour pixels in the predicted label ####

        for k in range(len(pos_list)):
            y_pred_copy[batch, pos_list[k][1]-3:pos_list[k][1], pos_list[k][2]-3:pos_list[k][2]+6, 0] = 0
            y_pred_copy[batch, pos_list[k][1]:pos_list[k][1]+3, pos_list[k][2]-3:pos_list[k][2], 0] = 0
            y_pred_copy[batch, pos_list[k][1]:pos_list[k][1]+3, pos_list[k][2]+3:pos_list[k][2]+6, 0] = 0
            y_pred_copy[batch, pos_list[k][1]+3:pos_list[k][1]+6, pos_list[k][2]-3:pos_list[k][2]+6, 0] = 0
   
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred_copy, dtype=tf.float32)

    #### END ####

    # Calculate true positives (tp), false negatives (fn) and false positives (fp)  

    tp = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=axis)
    fn = K.sum(y_true * (1-y_pred), axis=axis)
    fp = K.sum((1-y_true) * y_pred, axis=axis)
    tversky_class = (tp + smooth)/(tp + delta*fn + (1-delta)*fp + smooth)
    # Sum up classes to one score
    tversky_loss = K.sum(1-tversky_class, axis=[-1])
    # adjusts loss to account for number of classes
    num_classes = K.cast(K.shape(y_true)[-1],'float32')
    tversky_loss = tversky_loss / num_classes

    return tversky_loss
```

This implementation was runned using

```
model.compile(loss=modified_tversky_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics, run_eagerly=True)
```

and returns the following error

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:

which I believe happens because of some problem related with non differentiable operations.

I have tried to write this function using tensorflow functions only but among all my problems, the biggest issue I find is that it is not possible to assign values to a tf tensor in a similar way to numpy arrays.

Is there a way to write this function using tensors only ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with moving the identify_axis function inside the loss function?

Comment: I have not, but the function works properly with identity_axis outside when I remove the modifications I made to the original Tversky loss function.